# Spotipy: "module" object has no attribute "Spotify"

Tags: spotipy

I keep getting following message when trying to run Spotipy:

> AttributeError: `module` object has no attribute `Spotify`

Running a basic code copied from Spotify documentation:

```
import spotipy

spotify = spotipy.Spotify()
results = spotify.search(q='artist:' + name, type='artist')
print results
```

It seem to have worked before so wondering if updating to macOS Sierra could have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues/131

Rename something else from spotipy.py. Cheers!