# AttributeError Spotipy

Tags: python, spotipy

Earlier today I had no problem accessing the Spotipy API but all of a sudden it stopped working. When I forexample run the following:

`spotipy.artist("5rSXSAkZ67PYJSvpUpkOr7")`

Where `5rSXSAkZ67PYJSvpUpkOr7` is the Spotify ID of an artist, I get the error:

`AttributeError: module 'spotipy' has no attribute 'artist'`

The closest thing to an explanation I have found is this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950304/spotipy-module-object-has-no-attribute-spotify). But I don't completely understand the solution.

Comment: You have a file called `spotipy` in your own project. The explanation you linked tells you to rename it to something else.

Comment: @h4z3 I have tried to look through all my folders but I cant find a file or notebook called `spotipy`. I am using deepnote, don't know if that makes a difference?

Comment: See the first example of the [API reference](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/#api-reference)...

Answer (score 1):

Your `spotify` is apparently the module and not the object of `spotify_obj = spotify.Spotify()` class.

`spotify_obj` has `artist` attribute. `spotify` module does not.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was excatly my problem but it lead me to finding the problem. I accidently imported twice, so `import spotipy as sp` and `import spotipy`. Thanks! :-)